# Indi FinApp Data Model

Tags: api, rest, yodlee

I noticed that a few days ago you removed many data elements from your indi finapp documentation. As an example insurance or bills accounts are no longer listed. This is the page I'm referring to:
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model

Could you explain why this change was made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The team is going through and cleaning up the related articles and will repost when they are ready.